# 404 error when deploying ASP.NET Core 6 Web API to Azure Portal via Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I'm encountering an issue when trying to deploy my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project to Azure Portal using Azure DevOps. After completing the deployment process successfully, when I attempt to access the API through its URL in the browser, I get a http 404 error.

Here are the steps I've followed:

- Developed an API in .NET 6 that works fine in my local development environment.
- Configured a pipeline in Azure DevOps to build, package, and publish the API to Azure Portal.
- The deployment to Azure Portal seems successful as I don't see any errors in the deployment process.
- However, when I try to access the API's URL `https://projectms.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html`, I receive a 404 error.

I've done several checks, such as ensuring that routing in the code is configured correctly and there are no issues with the project's folder structure. I've also reviewed the deployment logs in Azure DevOps, but I can't find any clues about what might be causing the 404 error.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue when deploying an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API to Azure Portal via Azure DevOps? I would greatly appreciate any advice, solutions, or debugging steps you could suggest to address this problem.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I anticipated that after the successful deployment, I could access the API via its URL `https://projectms.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html` and see the expected response from the API endpoints.

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971
```

Pipeline YAML:

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 6.x'
  inputs:
    version: 6.x

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
    vstsFeed: '3952c5b3-4b63-4724-9a4f-062de60190c8'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: pekspro.pekspro-efcore-migration-script-generator.efcore-migration-script-generator.efcore-migration-script-generator-task@1
  displayName: 'Generate Migration Scripts'
  inputs:
    projectpath: ProjectMS/ProjectMS.csproj
    databasecontexts: Context
    startupprojectpath: ProjectMS/ProjectMS.csproj
    installdependencies: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Release YAML - Azure App Service Deploy

```
steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: ProjectMS'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Suscripción de Azure 1 (97f0131b-0b4b-45a5-816a-52e41cf4c041)'
    WebAppName: ProjectMS
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ProGest-ASP.NET Core-CI/drop/ProjectMS.zip'
```

Azure SQL SqlTask:

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Azure SQL SqlTask'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Suscripción de Azure 1 (97f0131b-0b4b-45a5-816a-52e41cf4c041)'
    ServerName: progest.database.windows.net
    DatabaseName: ProjectDB
    SqlUsername: CloudSA52ffd28c
    SqlPassword: Progest.Admin2023...
    deployType: SqlTask
    SqlFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ProGest-ASP.NET Core-CI/drop/migrations/Context.sql'
```

- [Pipeline Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQvcE.png)
- [Release Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fkSA.png)

Comment: Share your pipeline, including any relevant logs or error messages/warnings.

Comment: Ready, add the requested!

Answer (score 1):

***I tried deploying Azure Asp.net API in Azure Web app with Azure DevOps and it was successful, Refer below:-***

Refer my **SO thread answer** [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440816/no-package-found-with-specified-pattern-d-a-1-websitebr/76472534#76472534) for more insights.

**My Yaml pipeline:-**

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: 'publishedApp'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- job: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - download: current
    artifact: 'publishedApp'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'subscription-id'
      appType: 'webApp'
      appName: 'valleywebapp0986'
      package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

Make sure you set WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=0 in your Web app Configuration. And then edit the below code in your Web.config file in the Kudu tool like below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

For SQL Dacpac deployment, Refer my SO thread answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75826174/sqlazuredacpacdeployment-login-failed-for-user-token-identified-principal/75833673#75833673).