# Deploying .NET code to App Service using Azure Devops but SDK not found

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, devops

I am trying to deploy a .NET application to an AppService using Azure Devops but after successful deployment, I get the following errors. The SDK can not be found and I think it is not being installed.

````
Container psmapi20230825165938_0_693b3a8c couldn't be started: Logs = 2023-08-26T19:24:22.486642726Z    _____                               
2023-08-26T19:24:22.486705226Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2023-08-26T19:24:22.486710027Z  /  /_\  \\___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2023-08-26T19:24:22.486713827Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2023-08-26T19:24:22.486717027Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2023-08-26T19:24:22.486721427Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2023-08-26T19:24:22.486724627Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2023-08-26T19:24:22.486728127Z 
2023-08-26T19:24:22.486731427Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2023-08-26T19:24:22.486734527Z Dotnet quickstart: https://aka.ms/dotnet-qs
2023-08-26T19:24:22.486737727Z ASP .NETCore Version: 7.0.9
2023-08-26T19:24:22.486740827Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2023-08-26T19:24:23.703343205Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2023-08-26T19:24:24.132405374Z Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
2023-08-26T19:24:24.140660195Z Running oryx create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -defaultAppFilePath /defaulthome/hostingstart/hostingstart.dll     -bindPort 8080 -bindPort2 '' -userStartupCommand 'dotnet PSM.API.dll' 
2023-08-26T19:24:24.261889266Z Could not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2023-08-26T19:24:24.263062984Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2023-08-26T19:24:24.264163500Z Build Operation ID: f366726a-6ad3-47c1-af3b-345f3f28089c
2023-08-26T19:24:24.856953362Z 
2023-08-26T19:24:24.858207380Z Agent extension disabled
2023-08-26T19:24:24.858225180Z Before if loop >> DotNet Runtime 
2023-08-26T19:24:24.915536018Z DotNet Runtime 7.0Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2023-08-26T19:24:25.146690996Z Running user provided startup command...
2023-08-26T19:24:25.277529508Z The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
2023-08-26T19:24:25.277562208Z   * You intended to execute a .NET application:
2023-08-26T19:24:25.277567908Z       The application 'PSM.API.dll' does not exist.
2023-08-26T19:24:25.277577609Z   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
2023-08-26T19:24:25.277581709Z       No .NET SDKs were found.
2023-08-26T19:24:25.277585509Z 
2023-08-26T19:24:25.277589009Z Download a .NET SDK:
2023-08-26T19:24:25.277592609Z https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
2023-08-26T19:24:25.277596209Z 
2023-08-26T19:24:25.277599809Z Learn about SDK resolution:
2023-08-26T19:24:25.277603409Z https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found```
````

I am including my azure-pipelines.yml file

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'



- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'Sandbox(3)(5be9a3ef-42bb-4ec0-a213-76a6946ff5b9)'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: 'PSMAPI20230825165938'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)//**/*.zip'
    RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|7.0'
```

I would like to deploy a full working application but honestly this is the first time ever i work with a .net application

Answer (score 0):

I tried deploying Azure `ASP.net`  `.net 7.0 version`.  In Azure web app with the Azure devops pipeline and it worked successfully, Like below:-

**My .csproj file:-**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

***Instead of using VsBuild use UseDotNet@2 to install dotnet dependencies and SDK.***

**YAML code:-**

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '7.x'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: 'publishedApp'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- job: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - download: current
    artifact: 'publishedApp'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '7.x'

  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'subscription (xxxx598-xxx-b4fd-xxxx)'
      appType: 'webApp'
      appName: 'valleywebapp098'
      package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**Reference:-**

[c# - 404 error when deploying ASP.NET Core 6 Web API to Azure Portal via Azure DevOps - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76871485/404-error-when-deploying-asp-net-core-6-web-api-to-azure-portal-via-azure-devops/76873379#76873379)